# sonar credential issue while running jenkins build

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Jenkins version 1.480.3 and Sonar version 3.4.1. I am executing Sonar analysis on my project using maven build option "sonar:sonar -PsonarJs" and below properties in jenkins:-

```
sonar.login=sonar 
sonar.password=***** 
sonar.host.connectTimeoutMs=300000 
sonar.host.readTimeoutMs=600000 
projectVersion=${projectVersion} 
sonar.projectKey=abc 
sonar.projectName=abc 
sonar.projectVersion=${projectVersion} 
sonar.sources=${MyPath) 
sonar.branch=javascript 
sonar.language=js 
sonar.forceAnalysis=true
```

"sonar" is a local user created in Sonar.Upon firing the build in jenkins,sometimes my build fails with the following error:-

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project vos-generic: Can not execute Sonar: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.

```
This is an intermittent error, sometimes the build fails with this error and sometimes it is successful. 
I tried to resolve this error by creating a new local user "sonar1" in Sonar and adding it to the administrative group but got the same error again. 

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this ?